# What is the $_SERVER variable $_SERVER["HTTP_TE"]?

Tags: php

As I'm trying to configure my server, I made a var_dump of $_SERVER and noticed an (to me and a quick Google) unknown variable: what is the $_SERVER variable $_SERVER["HTTP_TE"]?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/TE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> All HTTP headers sent to the script are made available through the $*SERVER array, with names prefixed by 'HTTP*'.

`HTTP_TE` will be [a `TE` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/TE) sent by the client.

> The TE request header specifies the transfer encodings the user agent is willing to accept. (you could informally call it Accept-Transfer-Encoding, which would be more intuitive).

Comment: aha, that quote from the manual is somewhere from the User Contributed Notes, thanks!